# Getting graph api token using AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword method for a Federated user

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I've tried acquiring token using ROPC with the username and password provided by client. But the error message was "parsing_wstrust_response_failed". Same as the error message (last error) described [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication)

From this error message I understood my user is a federated user and cannot use this method. Is there any other way to acquire token for a federated user using username and password?

```
try
{
  result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes,
               "joe@contoso.com",
               securePassword)
               .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalClientException ex) when  (ex.ErrorCode=="parsing_wstrust_response_failed"){
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no way.
You need to handle the authentication with another flow.

I mentioned this downside in my recent article: https://joonasw.net/view/ropc-grant-flow-in-azure-ad

Comment: If the federated IdP supports it, this MSAL method *can* be used (though it's not ROPC, it's WS-Trust with with username/password against the federated IdP, and a token exchange with Azure AD).

Comment: Thanks Philippe :) I wasn't aware AAD would do that behind the scenes. Still doesn't meant you should use ROPC :P

Comment: MSAL does (the client-side library), not Azure AD. But **totally** agree with you that regardless of the protocol, this is a bad idea. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, a warning: You *really* should not use username/password in your app. In general, it's less secure and increases the risk you're exposing the associated environment to. It is also a brittle approach, as you will likely find Azure AD will require an interactive sign-in at some time in the future--probably at a very inconvenient time for you.

Second, a clarification: `AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword` will not always use the Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) OAuth 2.0 flow. When MSAL discovers that the user is part of a federated domain name, the library will attempt a non-interactive username/password authentication *if* the federated identity provider publishes an metadata exchange document which includes an endpoint supporting this method. If this request succeeds, MSAL will then attempt to exchange the response (issued by the federated identity provider) for the normal token set from Azure AD (issued by Azure AD).

So, to answer your question: It depends. It *is* possible to use `AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword` with a federated user. However, it requires that the federated identity service support this. AD FS, which is [the most common](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Best-way-to-connect-to-Office-365-and-Azure-AD-latest-data-Azure/ba-p/244205) IdP to be federated with Azure AD, supports this is the "usernamemixed" endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to build you could use the AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth() instead.  Our scenario was we needed a headless console app to be able to send emails and notifications to a Teams channel. We are also Federated, so username\password auth wouldn't work. But since we are running on on Windows we can use integrated auth.

I followed this guide to get the Access Token: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication

Our scenario did require a one time user consent, so the user the console app runs as had the proper permissions. https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&scope={scopes}